# Getting an error in an anonomous Execution - While doing a SELECT

Tags: soql

```
List<Observations__c> o = [SELECT Employee_Name__c  FROM Observations__c 
WHERE Employee_Name__c == 'Staff-0578'];
for(Observations__c b : o)
{
    b.Employee_Name__c  = 'Staff-0938';
}
update b;
```

**Line: 1, Column: 5
Unexpected token '<'.**

I cannot for the life of me figure out why I am getting this error.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the `==` in your query to `=`

```
List<Observations__c> o = [SELECT Employee_Name__c  FROM Observations__c 
WHERE Employee_Name__c = 'Staff-0578'];
```

Also, you cannot update `b` as its not valid out of for loop's scope.
so change `update b;` to

```
update o;// which is your original list.
```

Comment: Thanks! that solved it,  was driving me crazy.  Not sure why the error couldn't have pointed that out instead of showing me the first character LOL